# ToolBar change selected item

Tags: wpf, toolbar

I've created a toolbar that has 3 items of button type and has enough width to display 1 item (the rest in the dropdown box). How can i change the behaviour that when i click an item in the dropdown box the visible item changes to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the Toolbar.OverflowMode of the clicked item to OverflowMode.Never
and the Toolbar.OverflowMode of the other items to OverflowMode.Always

Example:

```
<ToolBar Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <Button Name="btn1" ToolBar.OverflowMode="Never" Click="btn1_Click">Button 1</Button>
  <Button Name="btn2" ToolBar.OverflowMode="Always" Click="btn2_Click">Button 2</Button>
  <Button Name="btn3" ToolBar.OverflowMode="Always" Click="btn3_Click">Button 3</Button>
</ToolBar>


private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ToolBar.SetOverflowMode(btn1, OverflowMode.Never);
  ToolBar.SetOverflowMode(btn2, OverflowMode.Always);
  ToolBar.SetOverflowMode(btn3, OverflowMode.Always);
}

private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ToolBar.SetOverflowMode(btn1, OverflowMode.Always);
  ToolBar.SetOverflowMode(btn2, OverflowMode.Never);
  ToolBar.SetOverflowMode(btn3, OverflowMode.Always);
}

private void btn3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ToolBar.SetOverflowMode(btn3, OverflowMode.Never);
  ToolBar.SetOverflowMode(btn1, OverflowMode.Always);
  ToolBar.SetOverflowMode(btn2, OverflowMode.Always);
}
```

A more generic way to do this:

```
  UIElement element = sender as UIElement;
  if (element != null) 
  {
    ToolBar.SetOverflowMode(element, OverflowMode.Never);

    foreach (var child in toolbar.Items) 
    {
      if (child is UIElement && child != element) 
      {
        ToolBar.SetOverflowMode((UIElement)child, OverflowMode.Always);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there another more generic way to do this? The number of buttons is only know at runtime.

Comment: Yes, you can iterate the toolbar items collection and set OverflowMode.Always to all children which are not the clicked button. See my updated answer for an example

Comment: Ok well it's generic but i need to add the event to each button. Is there another way?

Comment: Yes, you can handle the attached click event in the toolbar: `ButtonBase.Click="toolbar_Click"` and then do this: `if (e.Source != toolbar) UpdateToolbar(e.Source);`. The check is needed, otherwise you will get the clicks on the toolbar dropdown button.